# How Can I input values into a generic defined array list?

Tags: java, arrays, generics, insertion

I am working on a calculator like assignment for my data structures class, and I have to input symbols into the array list defined as

```
ArrayList<ScalarSymbol> scalar;
```

and I have been trying to input values into it by doing this:

```
scalars.add(0,')');
```

and it tells me that the char type is not the correct syntax for the `<ScalarSymbol>` array. I don't know how to find out what types the array will take, is there bind I have to use in order to make it accept chars?

Comment: I'm curious, what lead you to believe that `add(0, ')')` would do what you want? The [`ArrayList.add()` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add-E-) should be your canonical reference (and you can see it only takes one parameter), along with the [collections tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/) which covers interacting with `ArrayList` and other generic collections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create an instance of the object you want to add:

```
ScalarSymbol s = new ScalarSymbol();
```

Then add it to the list:

```
scalar.add(s);
```

The array list only takes the type written in these:

```
<type>
```